# Match a minimum number of concurrent lines in multiline regular expression

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I am looking for a pattern that will allow me to identify a range of text in a document that consists of a list of words. Use this text as an example.

```
property
subject
recipe
newsletter
news
match
reply
bulletin
joke
annual
greeting
accepted
puzzle
march
meeting
din
order
alert
printer
thursday
case
chicago
member
```

A run of text like this will often appear in the middle of HTML in spam email bodies. It is always a single word per line. The words are always in English so I don't have to worry about uff-8 characters. These words are meant to confuse the Bayes filters, but they should be easy to match.

I'm looking for a way to match several lines in a row. A simple regular expression like this will match a single line:

```
/^\w+$/
```

Now, I want to be able to find a minimum of 20 matching lines or more. How do I do that? Would it look something like this?

```
/^\w+${20,}/
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You need to group the expression inside parentheses so that the quantifier will apply to the whole expression, not just the immediately preceding character. You also need to put the line break itself into the regexp as well.

```
/(^\w+$\n){20,}/
```

Depending on the language you're using, you may also need to add the `m` (multi-line) modifier, so that `^` and `$` will match beginning and end of lines, not the whole input string.

```
/(^\w+$\n){20,}/m
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hJ0xI8/2)

Comment: Needed to add `\n` to match the newlines. See the demo now.

Comment: Perfect, well done, +1! But I noticed the group only contains `member` , is this normal ?

Comment: Thanks so much that did the trick. Thank you also for helping me to understand how important grouping was here. It makes perfect sense to me now.